# How to move file to a sublevel in s3 without triggering lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

An excel file (say my_excel_file.xlsx) will be uploaded to s3://my-bucket/a/b/

A trigger is set in lambda with following properties:
bucket-name: my-bucket, prefix: a/b/

I want my lambda to:

1. Read the excel file uploaded to s3://my-bucket/a/b/ into a pandas dataframe
2. After processing it, move the excel file to s3://my-bucket/a/b/archive/ with the name: my_excel_file_timestamp.xlsx

In case I am able to achieve the above step, will the lambda get invoked recursively? If yes, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Amazon S3 event is configured to trigger on prefix `a/b/`, then it will trigger the AWS Lambda function when an object is placed into `a/b/archive/`.

I recommend adding a line of code at the top of the Lambda function that checks the `Key`, which is passed to the function via the `event` parameter. It should check if the `Key` starts with `a/b/archive/` (or similar rule) -- if so, it should exit the function immediately. This will not incur a significant cost because it will exit quickly and Lambda is only charged per millisecond.

The alternative is to put your `archive` folder in a different location.